# Offset with pcolormesh, contour (Python matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

i'm trying to plot a 2D array with pcolormesh. It's a 2D axisymetric spherical plot of black hole magnetosphere. The problem is why there is an offset in theta ?...Normally the magnetic field lines must be vertical and slightly curved by the black hole at the equator. The map also seems to be offset. [Black hole magnetosphere (64 points)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Blrm.png) Here parts of my code which could be interesting:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import scipy.integrate as integrate

##### Natural unities 
M = 1.0
G = 1.0
c = 1.0 

##### Gravitational radius
rg = (G * M)/(c*c)

##### spin
a = 0.0

##### Horizon radius
rh = rg + np.sqrt(rg*rg - a*a)

##### r, theta parameters
rmin = 0.9*rh

rmax = 5.0

thmin = 0.001*np.pi
thmax = 0.999*np.pi

Nr = 64
Nth = 64

r = np.logspace(np.log10(rmin),np.log10(rmax),Nr)

th = np.linspace(thmin,thmax,Nth)

r_grid, th_grid = np.meshgrid(r,th)


x = r_grid*np.cos(th_grid)
y = r_grid*np.sin(th_grid)

##### ergosphere

rerg = 1.0 + np.sqrt(1.0-a*a*np.cos(th)*np.cos(th))

xerg = rerg*np.cos(th)
yerg = rerg*np.sin(th)

##### Horizon
xrh = rh*np.cos(th)
yrh = rh*np.sin(th)


############################# schwarzschild's metric


Alpha_sch = 1.0/np.sqrt(1.0+(2.0/r_grid))

sqr_det_gamma_sch = np.sqrt((1.0+2.0/r_grid)*r_grid*r_grid*r_grid*r_grid*np.sin(th_grid)*np.sin(th_grid))


Brg = np.zeros((Nth,Nr))


############################# Flux function

Psy = np.zeros((Nth,Nr))

V = [2,4,6,8,10,12]



##### Wald's solution
Brg = Alpha_sch*np.cos(th_grid)


for i in range (0,Nr):
    for j in range(1,Nth):
        th3 = th[0:j]
        Psy[j,i]=integrate.simps(sqr_det_gamma_sch[0:j,i]*Brg[0:j,i],th3)



plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.title('$B^r$')
circle1 = plt.Circle((0,0),rh,color = 'k')
ax.add_artist(circle1)
plt.contour(y,x,Psy,V,colors = 'k')
plt.pcolormesh(y,x,Brg,cmap='bwr',vmin=-1,vmax=1)
cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_label('Intensité', rotation=270)
plt.xlim(0,rmax)
plt.xlabel('$r_g$')
plt.ylabel('$r_g$')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Of course, if i take more points in r and theta the offset decrease but still be here [Black hole magnetosphere (256 points)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLIou.png). It would be very helpful if some of you can explain me why. Thanks you by advance.

Jérémy

Answer (score 0):

You are using `integrate.simps()` to do the integration, it need many points to get precise.

You can use `integrate.quad()` to do the integration, here is the code:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from math import sqrt, sin, cos

##### Natural unities 
M = 1.0
G = 1.0
c = 1.0 

##### Gravitational radius
rg = (G * M)/(c*c)

##### spin
a = 0.0

##### Horizon radius
rh = rg + np.sqrt(rg*rg - a*a)

##### r, theta parameters
rmin = 0.9*rh

rmax = 5.0

thmin = 0
thmax = np.pi

Nr = 64
Nth = 64

r = np.logspace(np.log10(rmin),np.log10(rmax),Nr)

th = np.linspace(thmin,thmax,Nth, endpoint=True)

r_grid, th_grid = np.meshgrid(r,th)

x = r_grid*np.cos(th_grid)
y = r_grid*np.sin(th_grid)

def f(th, r):
    th = float(th)
    r = float(r)
    Alpha_sch = 1.0/sqrt(1.0+(2.0/r))
    sqr_det_gamma_sch = sqrt((1.0+2.0/r)*r*r*r*r*sin(th)*sin(th))
    Brg = Alpha_sch*cos(th)
    return sqr_det_gamma_sch * Brg

Psy = np.zeros_like(x)
for i in range (0,Nr):
    for j in range(Nth):
        Psy[j, i] = integrate.quad(f, 0, th[j], args=(r[i],))[0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.pcolormesh(y, x, Psy)
ax.contour(y, x, Psy, colors="k")
```

and the output:

[image]